# Why does "npm start" work without "run", but no other script does?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

In my `package.json` file, there is the "scripts" section with my "start" script. When I type `npm start` it runs the "start" script. But for any other script, you have to run it by doing `npm run [script-name]`.

This makes me have 2 questions:

1. Why does the "start" script work without doing `npm run start`, but no other scripts work without "run"?
2. Is there any way to make other scripts run without doing `npm run [script-name]`?

   - With NPM, the answer is no.
     But if you look at the comment, it is said that you can use `yarn` to do this.

Comment: 1) Because that's how they wrote it. See [Life Cycle Operation Order](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-operation-order). 2) Yes, use `yarn`

Answer (score -2):

That's by convention. No, you cannot run other scripts without `run`.